# Are mailing lists on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Most online communities these days are web-based, and support editing and deleting community content (among other things).  Before web fora there were (and still are) mailing lists, which can also function as communities.  Mailing lists, unlike web-based communities, are write-once -- no editing or deleting community-wide.  (Of course, individual recipients can do whatever they want with the messages they receive.)

Are questions about the community/people aspects of mailing lists on-topic here?

Comment: I don't see why they wouldn't be. Why would this site limit itself to communities that communicate over a protocol based on HTTP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moderators.SE is (and in the proposal already was) intended to be about *communities*. There's a reason the matter of *community management* was brought up repeatedly. Of course that means mailing lists are on-topic as well - the behavioural patterns and required oversight, are similar.

The site does not even need to restrict itself to written or online communication, for that matter. Mostly anything that fits the topic of maintaining, managing and navigating a community should be perfectly on-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go so far as to include offline communities without further discussion ("how should I organize the pot-luck for our club's meet-up?"?), but accepting based on votes + the comment on the question (and its votes).

Comment: @MonicaCellio I love cross-linking questions, so let's create a loop and go back and forth: As I said on the more [offline/online-related question](http://meta.moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/58/), we definitely need to figure out just *where* our expertise ends, but there is a lot of overlap with offline communities that definitely fits our scope just as well.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out that question; I must have missed it in the initial flurry.